# What is the difference between $request->getControllerName() and $request->getParm("controller") when using _foward()

Tags: zend-framework

When using `$this->_forward()` in a Controller, in the resulting Controller the return for `$request->getControllerName()` returns the Controller Name from the first Controller.

But when using `$request->getParm("controller")` it returns the correct Controller for the current Controller.

Why are these different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Forward, it is still the same request. The "getControllerName" method checks for this. Get Param not..